# Simple proof that the order of an element of a group divides order of the group itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

The following theorem have been given to us:

"*Let $G$ be a group and $a \in G$ be an element of it. Let $k \in \mathbb Z^+$ be a positive integer. Suppose that $|a|=n$. Then $<a^k>=<a^{gcd(n,k)}>$ and $|a^k| = \frac{n}{gcd(n,k)}$.*"

I would like to know how to show from this theorem as a corollary, that for any finite cyclic group $G = <a>$ generated by arbitrary element $a \in G$, the order of any element $x \in G$ divides the order of the group $G$. Most proofs I've seen online are based around Lagrange's Theorem, but in this case, I don't want to be using Lagrange's Theorem.

Is there a very simple and straightforward way to prove this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $G$ is *generated* by $a$, then $\vert G \vert = \vert a \vert$.

Comment: @RobertShore I made a typo there. I meant to say any element of the group, and not just $a$.

Comment: Why do you object to using Lagrange's theorem?

Comment: The $<x>$ is a subgroup of $<a>$ and $<a>$ is a subgroup of $G$.  By Lagrange theorem $|x|$ divides $|<a>|$ and $|<a>|$ divides $|G|$. So $|x|$ divides $|G|$. QED.  Now tell me *why* you don't want to use Lagrange theory.  And tell me *why* you want to prove something that Lagrange theory makes *utterly* obvious.

Comment: @fleablood Because what I'm reading hasn't covered Lagrange's Theorem yet, and we need to prove it directly from the previous theorem, hence it being a *corollary*.

Comment: If the element $a$ has order $n$ then the set $\{1, a, a^2, \dots, a^{n-1} \}$ has cardinality $n$. Multiplying this set by any $x \in G$ does not change its cardinality: $ |\{1, a, a^2, \dots, a^{n-1} \}| = |\{x, xa, xa^2, \dots, xa^{n-1} \}|$. Now $G$ could be equal to $\{1, a, a^2, \dots, a^{n-1} \}$. If not pick  $x \in G$ that is not in $\{1, a, a^2, \dots, a^{n-1} \}$. Now $G$ as a set could be  equal to the disjoint union of $\{1, a, a^2, \dots, a^{n-1} \}$ and $\{x, xa, xa^2, \dots, xa^{n-1} \}$. If not, we do the same again. This implies $|G| = nk$. Roughly, this is Lagrange's thm.

Comment: But that's what the theorem says! It's clear that $\,n/g\,$ is a divisor of $n,\,$ explicitly $\,(n/g)\,g = n\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

This is immediate from the theorem that you're given.  If $a$ generates $G$ and $\vert a \vert = n$, then $\vert G \vert =n$ and the Theorem tells you $\vert a^k \vert = \frac{n}{\gcd (n, k)}$, so $\vert a^k \vert \gcd(n, k) = n$ and $\vert a^k \vert$ divides $n$.